# Korban for Purim

Tags: beis-hamikdash, purim, korban, temple-service-avoda

Being that the second Beis Hamikdash was built after (and possibly as a result of) the story of Purim, why was there not a specific (or general) korban that was brought in remembrance, or in thanks for the miracle of purim?

Comment: Didn’t you ask this once? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/135302/how-was-purim-celebrated-in-the-beis-hamikdash-with-korbanos

Comment: @Chatzkel Different question. I am curious as to why no korbanos had been instituted,

Comment: Do we ever have a korban miderabbanan? I don’t think such a thing is possible

Comment: @JoelK There's קיץ המזבח. Don't see why they couldn't plan for some of those on any particular day.

Comment: @DoubleAA that wouldn’t be described as a special remembrance out thanks that the OP asked. Any new korban would probably be considered chullin bazara

Comment: @Chatzkel If they purposefully planned a bunch of them for then it certainly could be described that way. Not sure why you think it would be chullin. It may not be obligatory but it would presumably have been sanctified as a korban.